Need help, Azure Bot not working as expected, getting Unauthorized error OR HTTP internal server error, how to resolve this?
Need help on resolving Microsoft Azure Bot framework composer errors
I am getting Azure Bot errors
Context

used DotNet 7
tested in both empty bot and simple bot
windows machine
windows image
GitHub actions - (for CD)
Microsoft Bot Framework Composer - (for direct deployment or publish)

All Logs
https://rentry.co/me78ps7r

Tried Resolution


Reset System
Using GitHub Action
Deploying / Publishing through Microsoft Bot Framework composer


Hi there, welcome to SO. May I assume you were using GitHub Action for deployment rather than using Azure DevOps pipeline right?

I have tried this 2 ways for deployment

Microsoft Bot Framework Composer
GitHub Action


@jaydeep-promact Share your code what you have tried.




I using this GitHub Action for CICD - https://rentry.co/9xz9oav5 ---- and also tried directly publishing the bot from Microsoft Bot Framework composer 2.1.2 "Windows software" publish option.




I have followed below steps to create and deploy the C# Bot to Azure; it worked as expected.

Created a C# Empty Bot using Azure Bot Composer.

Local Response:



Add below settings in Settings=>appsettings.json:

  "MicrosoftAppId": "<Microsoft_App_ID_of_Bot>",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "Microsoft_password_ID_of_Bot(or)client_secret",
  "MicrosoftAppType": "MultiTenant",
  "MicrosoftAppTenantId": "TenantID",


Pushed the code to GitHub:
Deployed the application to Azure App Service(Windows) with .NET7 as runtime stack using GitHub actions:

GitHub Workflow:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - appname

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '7.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_034AC5XXXXX28 }}


Deployment Status:


Update the messaging endpoint of the Bot with https://webappname.azurewebsites.net/api/messages:


Test the connection in Web Chat of the Azure Bot:


thanks but .. can you please try deploying or publishing with directly from Bot Framework Composer 2.1.2 ?

I could deploy using Bot Framework composer as well.

yeah sure... please can you test it same way as you did above.. if possible
